# Jenkins build number changing to data and time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to change the build number format (e.g. `#10`) to the date/time format `YYYYMMDD-SSMMHH`, e.g., `20160812-062713`.

I have tried the *build-name-setter* and *version number* plugins, which did not help me adding date and time. Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Build Timestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Timestamp+Plugin) can produce an environment variable `${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}` that can be read and applied by the [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin).